Forward implied volatility definition
I am struggling to understand the link between two definitions of forward implied volatility. The well kwown model free forward implied volatility from $T_1$ to $T_2$ is defined as:
$$
\sigma_F(T_1, T_2, K)=\sqrt{\frac{\sigma(T_2,K)^2T_2-\sigma(T_1,K)^2T_1}{T_2-T_1}}.
$$
In this paper, the forward implied volatility is implicitely defined as (p15):
$$
C_\mathrm{Model}(T_1,T_2, K) = e^{-rT_1}C_{\mathrm{BS}}(K, T_2-T_1, \sigma_F(T_1, T_2, K)).
$$
Are both of them equivalent formulas ?
Thank you very much!

They're not equivalent. The first is a measure of the term structure of the implied variance / implied vol of vanilla options.
The second should probably be more accurate called Type I forward start implied volatility, as it is the implied volatility of options with the following payout (called Type I forward start options):
$$
E_0 \left[ \left( \frac{S_T}{S_t} - \alpha \right)_+ \right]
$$
There is also the Type II forward start implied volatility, which is the IV of options with the following payout (called Type II forward start options):
$$
E_0 \left[ \left( S_T - \alpha S_t \right)_+ \right]
$$
(Btw: the link does not work, at least not for me.)

Te DOI link should work: http://dx.doi.org/10.2139/ssrn.1823769

@DimitriVulis Ty, your link works.

The Researchgate link tells me: "checking whether you're human" and then "Access denied" - I failed their Turing test.

Sorry for the delay of my answer. Thank you very much for your detailed post @Frido

No, the second one depends on hitting an arbitrary price. If that price is intrinsic, the the implied vol is 0.
First one depends on market information of today, which may imply something different in the future, there is no guarantee that the market is interested in getting the forward vol right when trading vanillas. It is only usable if underlying dynamics are lognormal for sure.
If in the second one, the model is BS, then I think it is the same as first.
If you can tell us how you want to use this, we can help you with more.
Thanks!
